# DialogFragment with RecyclerView issue in onCreateDialog

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I need to add in my DialogFragment positive/negative button.
This is the dialog without these buttons:
[image]

and this is the code I've used to implement it:

```
public class RecyclerColorsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerColorsDialogAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Boolean>colorChecked;
ArrayList<String>items;
ArrayList<String>colors;

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setCancelable(true);



    return dialog;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_colors_dialog, container, false);

    colorChecked = new ArrayList<>(12);
    colors = new ArrayList<>(12);

    String[] cItems = {getString(R.string.red),getString(R.string.green), getString(R.string.blue),getString(R.string.yellow),
    getString(R.string.azur),getString(R.string.black),getString(R.string.white),getString(R.string.gray),getString(R.string.brown),
    getString(R.string.pink),getString(R.string.purple)};

    items = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(cItems));

    //inizializzo i check a false
    for (int i = 0; i< items.size(); i++)
     colorChecked.add(true);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recColors);
    adapter = new RecyclerColorsDialogAdapter(getActivity(),colors,colorChecked,items);

    final Dialog dialog = getDialog();

    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setTitle("Add a picture to your aircraft:");

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
{
    super.onCancel(dialog);
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    dialog.cancel();
}
}
```

and it's the call from other fragment:

```
final RecyclerColorsDialogFragment dialog = new RecyclerColorsDialogFragment();
    dialog.setTargetFragment(AddAicraftFivePartFragment.this, 2);


    logo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            dialog.show(manager, "PATAG");
```

I have a problem when I try to do it in `onCreateDialog()`:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 //        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
 //       dialog.setCancelable(true);

return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            // do something...
                        }
                    }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
            ).create();


   // return dialog;
}
```

because it shows it:
   [image]

without recyclerview with items.
   How could I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put code from onCreate to onCreateDialog. Then set the rootView to the dialog view. And remove the onCreate() method

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).
                setTitle("Add a picture to your aircraft:").setMessage(mMessage).
                setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.discard), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(getString(android.R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        Inflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_colors_dialog, container, false);

        colorChecked = new ArrayList<>(12);
        colors = new ArrayList<>(12);

        String[] cItems = {getString(R.string.red), getString(R.string.green), getString(R.string.blue), getString(R.string.yellow),
                getString(R.string.azur), getString(R.string.black), getString(R.string.white), getString(R.string.gray), getString(R.string.brown),
                getString(R.string.pink), getString(R.string.purple)};

        items = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(cItems));

        //inizializzo i check a false
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
            colorChecked.add(true);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recColors);
        adapter = new RecyclerColorsDialogAdapter(getActivity(), colors, colorChecked, items);


        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        dialog.setView(rootView)
        return dialog.create();
    }
```

Comment: WHAAAT?? if you put all the code from `onCreateView` into `onCreateDialog`, then how are you supposed to inflate the layout? Where does the root view come from? What `inflater.inflate` variable to take from?? Where does the `container` come from??? How in the hell is this accepted as a solution?

Comment: @busuu now edited the answer. inflater and container came from onCreateView method.

Comment: cant understand anything from this answer

Comment: You can't return dialog.create(). This have void as return type but view is required